# Numpy, how to repeat an array's elements according to corresponding numbers in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the best way to repeat the elements of an array according to the corresponding numbers in another array? For example, given:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([100,50,200,10])
b = np.array([0.5,0.1,0.15,0.25])
```

How can I have an array `c` that includes numbers from `b` repeated according to the numbers in `a` :

```
c = [0.5, 0.5, ..., 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, ... 0.1, 0.15, ..., 0.15, 0.25, ..., 0.25]
```

where the counts of 0.5, 0.1, 0.15 and 0.25 are respectively 100, 50, 200, and 10.

I know I can do it by using a for loop along with `np.repeat` and packing results in an array. But is there a better way in numpy to do this?

Comment: Why for loop? Just use in a single call to `np.repeat`.

Comment: No loop necessary. `np.repeat(b,a)` works as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([100,50,200,10])

b = np.array([0.5,0.1,0.15,0.25])

c = np.repeat(b,a)
```